# How to show full report on "relative importance" of variables for RapidMiner deep learning model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, rapidminer

I trained a deep learning model in RapidMiner and would like to see the relative importance that RapidMiner assigned to each variable.

Overall there are 128 variables in my model. After selecting "compute variable importances" in the design-tab under deep learning parameters ([See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCgON.png)), the "Deep learning"-report in the results tab only showed the importances assigned to the first 10 and last 10 variables ([See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lHTY.png)). That means there are 108 variables missing in the report.

How can I see the importances for all of the variables that are not shown in the "Deep learning"-report?

Comment: If there is any additional information that would be helpful to answer my question, please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found three options to solve my problem:

1. Use "Auto Model" and use its "Explain Predictions" function to see weights
2. Add "Explain Predictions"-process in design-view to see weights in results-view
3. Connect "deep learning"-operator in "design"-view from "weights"-connector to "results"-connector